# Coverity - Get project ID by Project name in command line

Tags: coverity

For a project, I have created project in Coverity Server and 2 streams for Java and CPP in that proejct.

I'm running coverity for the project in Jenkins. And coverity report will be append in mail template.

I also want to give a link to the project in the coverity server.

Like `http://192.168.1.20:8081/defects/index.htm?projectId=10068`.

I found out the project will be listed only after the coverity is finished running and then only I can see project and project ID in server.

If I get the project ID, I can create the project link.

I'm running below code in script to export report to csv file by passing Project Name.

```
/opt/coverity/cov-sa-linux64-5.5.3/bin/cov-manage-im --mode defects --show --action Undecided --project Jenkins_Week34_Coverity --host 192.168.1.20 --user admin --password admin123 --port 8081 --fields cid,file >/opt/cov/curr.csv
```

Similar way, is there any way to get the project ID by passing Project Name?

Or while committing report to server, do we get project id?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to craft a link that uses search parameters, using your values as an example the below should allow you to send the email:

```
http://192.168.1.20/query/defects.htm?project=Jenkins_Week34_Coverity
```

Note that the project name is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the answer by:

1. Api list all Project name also ProjectKey (project ID):

> curl -u username:pw https://your-coverity-server/api/v2/projects

2. Or you can get specific project info:

> curl -u username:pw
> https://your-coverity-server/api/v2/projects/project-name